# Hover effect not working with flexbox in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, hover, flexbox

When I have a flexbox with a centered item, the :hover pseudo-class does not work properly in Chrome. Hovering is only registered for the top 3/4 of the centered item, and not the bottom quarter. [gif showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al6iA.gif)

```css
#container {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(67, 67, 67, 0.8);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex;
}

#img-container {
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  border-radius: 140px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#img-container:hover {
  border: 5px solid red;
}

#under {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="img-container"></div>
</div>
<div id="under"></div>
```

Comment: It's showing fine here in chrome 47

Comment: @Scott: Odd, I'm on Chrome 49 on OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve it. Giving `#img-container` a `z-index` makes `:hover` work properly.

Answer (score 0):

When I have a flexbox with a centered item, the :hover pseudo-class Successfully work properly  in Chrome.

Comment: I wanted to be sure it wasn't just me so I've tested it with a few more people and they all get the same issue I'm reporting (:hover not working on the bottom 30% of the circle). I don't know why it's working for some.